# Getting started with free trial

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

Im trying to sign up for the "try cloud platform for free" (https://console.cloud.google.com/freetrial?_ga=1.88612569.317087374.1490559650&page=0), but it wont allow me to select the current payment profile I have on my google account (it is grayed out) and also wont allow me to create a new "personal" account type, only business (my current location is not the US, is Ireland)

What do I need to do to create an account and use the $300 free trial?
Thanks

Comment: This question does not seem to be about programming, because it is about Google's promotional policies.  Perhaps try asking Google sales or on a Google forum.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a business. Go to companies registration office and set up a company

https://www.cro.ie/Registration/Company

Next go to AIB and set up a business banking account

http://business.aib.ie/

You now have a business with a company account, only downside is that this may affect your pension or benefit rights....

Comment: thank for your answer. Are you saying google doesnt create Persona profile accounts outside the US?

Comment: @Diego based on the form it's business only.  In Ireland it costs about €25 to start a business...